# Can not align the text that comes from an API in Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, alignment

I'm designing an app that contains many recyclerRows and that rows contain Ticker and price data. The problem is that i can't align all price values neatly and nicely. They are in a mess and it is disgusting. I tried some alignment methods but they did not work.

My XML file:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/coinTicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/sen_bold"
    android:text="COIN NAME"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/coinPrice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/sen"
    android:text="PRICE"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textSize="30sp">
</TextView></LinearLayout>
```

---

ScreenShot:

[image]

Comment: set the fixed width for "coinTicker" then make it auto scrollable.

Comment: @Sevban You can align them by weight, Give these properties to both TextViews layout_width = 0 & layout_weigh t= 1

Answer (score 0):

I setted a fix value for coinTicker and made it autoScrollable. As @PejmanAzad
suggested.

Problem fixed this way

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).